# How do I join the current item in a list to items in another list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I've got a list of items in a list, say issues, and have linked to these from another list, say subIssues.

Using sharepoint designer 2007 i have successfully linked the 2 lists on the dispForm.aspx page, however it simply shows all the joins.  I need to link it to the currenty item, i.e. the item ID that is currently being viewed.

So instead of showing all the joined data, is there a way to only show the data with that is relevant to the current item.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of [this](http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--design-customization/filteringing-data-view-web-part-based-on-a-custom-column-6098.shtml).  Was simply a case of inserting a custom list form in display mode and then linking to it using the web part connections and filtering my data view on that.